# How can you test NFC on android if the 4.xx doesn't support it

Tags: android, emulation, nfc

I seems from other posts that enabling NFC hardware support in the emulator is not offered in 4.xx.

This brings me to the questions of how to test NFC. Rollback to a previous SDK version? Or buy supporting hardware requiring hundreds of dollars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Testing NFC is impossible without hardware, just as testing WiFi, GPS, Bluetooth, graphics acceleration, and so on is impossible without hardware. The emulator is great for pure software features of Android, but the closer you get to the "bare metal", the more you need actual hardware.

Moreover, since NFC usually interacts with other non-Android NFC technology (NFC tags, etc.), an emulator is even less useful, since you cannot wave an NFC tag in front of an emulator and get a reaction.